# Javascript asynchronous for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, for-loop, asynchronous

Is there a way for me run codes asynchronously in a for loop?

In this example, events from day **x** to **y** are required to be added into the calendar through a for loop. However the loop is taking roughly a min and its too long, as it is required to go through and add all the days from Jan 4, 2016 to Dec 28, 2020.

Right now, I will have to wait for all the days to be loaded to view the result.
Is there a way for events to get added and appear as soon as the 'addEventSource' is fired / before it goes through all the whole loop. Is it possible to make it asynchronous?

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        loadCalendar(null);
        var start = new Date("Jan 4, 2016 08:00:00");
        var end = new Date("Dec 28, 2020 12:00:00");
        var startTime = new Date("Jan 4, 2016 08:00:00");
        var endTime = new Date("Jan 4, 2016 12:00:00");

        addCalendarEvents("Test", start, end, startTime, endTime);
    });

function addCalendarEvents(title, start, end, repeatDays, startTime, endtime) {
        var events = [];

        var one_day = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        var loopEnd = end.getTime();

        for (var loop = start.getTime() ; loop <= loopEnd; loop = loop + one_day) {
            var eventDate = new Date(loop);

                var tempStart = start;
                var tempEnd = end;

                tempStart.setDate(eventDate.getDate());
                tempStart.setMonth(eventDate.getMonth());
                tempStart.setFullYear(eventDate.getFullYear());
                tempEnd.setDate(eventDate.getDate());
                tempEnd.setMonth(eventDate.getMonth());
                tempEnd.setFullYear(eventDate.getFullYear());

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
                    title: title,
                    start: tempStart,
                    end: tempEnd,
                    allDay: false
                }]);

        }
    }
```

p.s. `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', event) adds events to the calendar.`

Comment: Why are you trying to add the whole calendar events at once? Why not add for the viewing month only? The details received from the service can be stored locally to avoid service calls on every month change

Comment: @RavitejaAvvari That's not the only problem, even if events for the viewing month are added only, it still takes a huge amount of time when a large chunk of events are required to be loaded. What if there are more repeated events, the problem will still persist. Events can't be stored locally too, as they are required to be dynamic, and i'm planning to fire the addCalendarEvents function from a server as well.

Comment: If your events are (or are gonna be) stored on your server, this is server-side business to retrieve the events. Client side (js) you just need to tell : "Hey, I'm requesting the events from May 2018, or whatever". Request it to the server, server gives you back events, then you display. I think your approach is not good as @RavitejaAvvari says, you do not really "need" to get everything 'til 2020!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have a threading model, but it does have asynchronous timers.

Check this out: http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/

Comment: So how can i apply? Do you mind typing out the codes?

Answer (score 0):

As Tibrogargan mentioned, it can be achieved using setTimeout/setInterval.

The idea is to run the for loop for certain time and break the loop. again trigger the loop after certain time from where it has stopped earlier. This way you will not block the user.

eg..

```
var thresholdTime = 500;
function searchForData(searchTerm, indexFromWhereToSearch) {
  var startTime = new Date(),
    searchFrom = indexFromWhereToSearch;
  for (var i=searchFrom; i < hugeData.length; i++) {
    .......
    if (newDate() - startTime >= thresholdTime) {
      setTimeout((function(index) {
        return function() {
          searchForData(searchTerm, index);
        }
      })(i+1), 300/*another threshold*/);
      break/return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's going to work, but im new to this, how do i apply it to my code? Do you mind modifying them for me? Thanks! :)